# How to pass data from .cs to .js?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Normally when I include a pie chart in my code, I just simply put the code to generate the chart at the bottom of the page. Since i need to create more and more chart..to avoid a lot of script in my dashboard.aspx. I create a new .js file called dashboard.js and I include the js in my Dashboard.aspx as follows:

Dashboard.aspx

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="PieSource"></asp:HiddenField>  
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" align="center" style="font-size:10px;white-space:nowrap; width:50%; border:0px;">
        <div id="pie_chart" style="position:center; width:100%; height:200px; font-size:10px;"></div>  
    </td>
</tr>
...
...

<script src="/assets/js/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The data comes from Dashboard.aspx.cs as follow:

```
// Some query here
while(db.readDataSource)
{
    if (pieData.Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        pieData = "{ label: \"" + db.readValue("Name").ToString() + "\", value: " + db.readValue("Total").ToString() + " }";
    else
    {
        pieData += ", { label: \"" + db.readValue("Name").ToString() + "\", value: " + db.readValue("Total").ToString() + " }";
    }
}
db.closeDataReader();

 PieSource.Value = pieData.ToString();
```

Here is my dashboard.js

```
var Source = function () {
    if ($('#pie_chart').length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Morris.Donut({
        element: 'pie_chart',
        data: [<%= PieSource.Value %>], 
        colors: [
            '#745BEF',
            '#7B57E7',
            '#9E45C1',
            '#D32989',
            '#E9305D',
            '#ED4A3E',
            '#EF5C29',
            '#EF7326'
        ],
    });
}
```

So now.. how do i pass PieSource.Value in dashboard.js? No error that i get but my chart didn't display.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error.. thanks to @Mate.. I manage to display my chart now..
All i need is to send the variable to js in Dashboard.aspx (before dashboard.js)

```
var pieData = [<%=PieSource.Value %>];
```

Then in dashboard.js.. call back pieData into data as follows:

```
var Source = function () {
if ($('#pie_chart').length == 0) {
    return;
}

Morris.Donut({
    element: 'pie_chart',
    data: pieData, 
    colors: [
        '#745BEF',
        '#7B57E7',
        '#9E45C1',
        '#D32989',
        '#E9305D',
        '#ED4A3E',
        '#EF5C29',
        '#EF7326'
    ],
});
```

}

Thats all.. thanks for your help..